# How can I contribute content to bitcoincore.org?

Tags: news-coverage, contribution

I want to contribute relevant quality content to bitcoincore.org that would be valuable to its readers.

Answer (score 1):

The source code for bitcoincore.org (the website) is maintained via a GitHub repository. Content updates are proposed and reviewed by means of pull requests. Instructions for contributing to the website can be found in the repo's [CONTRIBUTING.md](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/bitcoincore.org/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

Given that this question was tagged with "news", I am wondering whether the purpose of the bitcoincore.org website is clear. The above linked contribution guidelines state:

> **Content Policy**
>
> The purpose of the website is to be an official mouthpiece for the
> Bitcoin Core project as well as be a resource for technical
> information that has a direct impact on Bitcoin Core software. This
> can include research, presentations, and developer blogs.
>
> Where proposed content is about Bitcoin Core project policy, there
> should rough consensus of the Bitcoin Core project maintainers as a
> minimum bar and final decision is with the Bitcoin Core project lead.
>
> <sub>via
> [CONTRIBUTING.md#content-policy](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/bitcoincore.org/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#content-policy),
> retrieved 2020-06-27</sub>

News seems out of scope per these guidelines.